# When I start new project on android studio 3.5 it shows "my application syncing..." forever and ever

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

My android studio (ver 3.5) doens't sync, and shows "my application syncing..." forever. ( actually i couldn't wait more than 8 hours)

I'm beginner in android studio.
first i've installed 3.2 ver and i had problems with Gradle which i couldn't solve. then i tried to update the SDK, NDK, Gradle and even whole android studio to ver3.5 .

now when i open android studio and create a project , it doesn't even sync!
it shows me that my application is still syncing (and never sync)(even i tried proxy and other networks) And there shows 1 error which is:

```
3:29 AM: Gradle sync failed: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of com/intellij/ide/plugins/cl/PluginClassLoader) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "gnu/trove/TObjectHashingStrategy (6 s 311 ms)
```

I even cannot change the Gradle codes or any other codes inside the android studio...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to update/change the grdale files, but still got same problem.
Some masters tried to fix it but they couldnt :|
after 3 days of trying there was actually one only way so i removed the whole software and installed it again and it fixed ... :|

I'm still confused

thanks you all <3

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you are iranian. if you live in Iran you must use a VPN or proxy to use Android studio because of U.S sanction.
a better way is to change your DNS introduced in https://shecan.ir/ .

Comment: well actually i used fodev.org proxy which is specially made for android studio and it works fine

Comment: by the way this DNS method you offered is wonderful and Im using it every single moment ;) thanks Hadi

Answer (score 0):

Try to invalidate your cache on "File -> Invalidate caches / Restart..."

Answer (score -1):

1) Invalidate caches and restart

2) uncheck the **Offline work** in Global Gradle settings under settings
**NB:** Have a stable internet connection for 2)